Translation of a phrase with a comma
I'm trying to translate:

It is not a time to blame the past; it is a time to fear the future.

I'm getting:

Non est tempus praeteritum reprehendere, tempus est timere future

I need to reword to avoid the comma, but I don't know what that means.

The English would also need punctuation, properly either a period or a semicolon, but informally a comma as well. The way you wrote the English makes it a run-on sentence.

You can throw in a sed (meaning "but") in place of a comma:

Non est tempus praeteritum reprehendere sed tempus est timere futurum.

You might consider other ways to word the sentence, that work Latin idioms more. For example, the plural praeterita suggests "things that happened"; ventura is "things to come". You can probably work the chiasmus harder, too:

Praeterita noli nunc culpare, potius horresce ventura.

"Don't now blame past events; better that you be terrified of what is to come." (It's snappier in Latin.)
I recommend awaiting another answer. Someone with more command of classical Latin than I have can probably suggest something more eloquent. (I think noli is a bit weak.)

I would use the gerund forms arguendi and timendi:

Non arguendi praeterita est tempus sed futura timendi.

And instead of the singular for "past", I used praeterita ("the things that have passed") and futura ("the things that are to come").
I also agree with Ben Kovitz's comment that sed is a good option instead of a comma.
